# SQL DB2 - Case statement with Y or N for different values with same column

Tags: sql

I have a complex SQL which is returning values in multiple columns, I need to return the output to a single row.

```
select distinct TableA.ColumnA, d.name,
      (CASE WHEN rel1.REL_TYPE = 'FG' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS  FG
      (CASE WHEN rel2.REL_TYPE = 'F1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS  F1,
      (CASE WHEN rel3.REL_TYPE = 'F2' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS  F2,
      (CASE WHEN rel4.REL_TYPE = 'F3' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS  F3 
 from TableA d
      inner join TableB p on TableA.ColumnA = p.ColumnB
      inner join TableC rel1 on  TableA.ColumnA = rel1.ColumnC  
        inner join TableC rel2 on  TableA.ColumnA = rel2.ColumnC 
        inner join TableC rel3 on  TableA.ColumnA = rel3.ColumnC 
        inner join TableC rel14 on  TableA.ColumnA = rel4.ColumnC        
where d.language_id   = -1  and  TableA.ColumnA = 53635
  and p.language_id   = -1
order by 1
 with ur;
```

And output has multiple rows, which I need to output to single row

```
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  N   N   N   N
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  N   N   N   Y
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   N   N   N
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   N   N   Y
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  N   Y   N   N
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  N   Y   N   Y
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   Y   N   N
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   Y   N   Y
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  N   N   Y   N
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  N   N   Y   Y
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   N   Y   N
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   N   Y   Y
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  N   Y   Y   N
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  N   Y   Y   Y
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   Y   Y   N
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   Y   Y   Y
```

I am looking for a single row output displaying Y or N for rel_type of FG, F1, F2 and F3 correspondingly(rel_type will consist of many rel_types like MN, OG etc)

```
53635   Fitness Fleece, Jacket  Y   Y   Y   N
```

Comment: What do you mean by "single row"? Assuming that with real data each row will have different values, it would be REALLY LONG ROW, with enormous number of COLUMNS in this row, practically impossible to present on the screen conveniently for reader. Do you mean GROUP BY ? In that case you will need to provide an aggregate expression for columns with different values. Theoretically you could force single row with some sophisticated SQL expression, nested JOINs, but this is typically a task for end-user interface, not SQL itself.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your desired output? The multiple rows output does have meaning.

Comment: You do not have the same values in each row, what do you want the final output to be?

Comment: I am looking for the output something like '53635 Fitness Fleece, Jacket Y Y Y N'

Comment: I think more explanation is needed.  The way I see it it can be none, any or all and if so how do you differentiate what is unique about row one compared to row two?  I guess the question is what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: Why?  How do you get Y Y Y N -- can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I am looking for a single row output displaying Y or N for rel_type of FG, F1, F2 and F3 correspondingly(rel_type will consist of many rel_types like MN, OG etc)

Comment: @user1970783 -- you still haven't explained why is FG = "Y" and why is F3 = "N" -- we don't understand the logic :)

Comment: @sgeddes -- sorry for not providing the necessary information. my database has some values of rel_type like FG, F1, F2, MN, OF, KI, F3 etc. I am interested in rel_types of FG, F1, F2, F3 and if my Database has FG, I should show Y else N saying FG exist or doesn't exist for that TableA.ColumnA(same way for F1, F2 or F3). I will be happy to provide more information if required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I finally understand the requirements.  You can use `MAX` with `CASE` and `GROUP BY` -- no need to join the table on itself:

```
select columna, 
  name,
  max(case when rel_type = 'FG' then 'Y' else 'N' end) 'FG',
  max(case when rel_type = 'F1' then 'Y' else 'N' end) 'F1',
  max(case when rel_type = 'F2' then 'Y' else 'N' end) 'F2',
  max(case when rel_type = 'F3' then 'Y' else 'N' end) 'F3'
from tablea
group by columna, name
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13da9/2)

Obviously add your `WHERE` criteria back, but this should be what you're looking for.